# Ubuntu Tweak natural scrolling not persistent

Tags: 12.04, unity, chromebook, ubuntu-tweak

I am using Ubuntu tweak on Ubuntu 12.04 and the natural scrolling setting does not persist after restart. So is there a way to permanently enable natural scrolling? If I have left any details out please tell me and I will add them as I am new to this.

System Details:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- processor ARMv7
- memory 2.0 GiB
- Unity 2D

My Ubuntu installation is on a Samsung Chromebook through crouton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the scrolling issue was caused by the crouton installer which is now updated with a fix for the bug thus anyone with this issue should update the crouton file with the [Instructions located here](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#a-new-version-of-crouton-came-out-my-chroot-is-therefore-obsolete-and-sad).

If you can not get to those instructions here is a copy of them(All rights go to the crouton creators):

1. Check for updates, download the latest version, and see what's new by running `croutonversion -u -d -c` **from the chroot** (run `croutonversion -h` to see what those parameters actually do).
2. **Exit the chroot** and run `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n chrootname`. It will update all installed targets.
3. You can use this with `-e` to encrypt a non-encrypted chroot, but make sure you **don't interrupt the operation**.